# chained select box bootstrap in codeigniter

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

i make select box from bootstrap and populate data from database to select box. I'm using codeigniter. But i got error messages 'illegal string offset'
[image]

this is my view

```
<?php foreach($option_provinsi as $data) { ?>
<option value=""><?=$data['nama_provinsi']?></option>
<?php } ?>
```

this is my controller

```
public function second_steps($page = 'payment_step_second') {
    $this->order_model->get_provinsi();
    $data['option_provinsi'] = $this->order_model->get_provinsi();

    $this->load->view('user/templates/header_payment', $data);

    $this->load->view('user/pages/' . $page, $data);
    $this->load->view('user/templates/footer_payment', $data);
}
```

this is my model

```
public function get_provinsi(){
    $result = array();
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('provinsi');
    $this->db->order_by('nama_provinsi','ASC');
    $array_keys_values = $this->db->get();
    foreach ($array_keys_values->result() as $row)
    {
        $result[0]= '-Pilih Propinsi-';
        $result[$row->id_provinsi]= $row->nama_provinsi;
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Thanks before

Answer (score 0):

what you are doing looks a bit wrong - try the following

your model:

```
public function get_provinsi()
{
    $obj = new stdClass();
    $obj->nama_provinsi = "-Pilih Propinsi-";


    $result = array(
        0   => $obj
    );

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('provinsi');
    $this->db->order_by('nama_provinsi','ASC');
    $query = $this->db->get();

    foreach ($query->result() as $row)
    {
        $result[]= $row;
    }

    return $result;
}
```

your controller

```
public function second_steps($page = 'payment_step_second')
{
    $data = array('option_provinsi' => $this->order_model->get_provinsi());

    $this->load->view('user/templates/header_payment', $data);

    $this->load->view('user/pages/' . $page, $data);
    $this->load->view('user/templates/footer_payment', $data);
}
```

and finally your view

```
<?php foreach($option_provinsi as $data) { ?>
    <option value=""><?=$data->nama_provinsi; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
```